# How to join two tables having one to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've one user table and another user_project table which contains primary key of user as its foreign key and user can have one or more projects. 
I need to join these tables to get comma separated project names for particular user.

I've tried something like this -

```
select group_concat(epi.project_name)
from user u
     inner join employee_projects_info epi on epi.employee_id= u.id
group by epi.project_name
```

but it is not giving me list of projects user wise.

Comment: Have you tried grouping by `epi.employee_id`?

Answer (score 0):

remove `epi.project_name` from `group by`, add epi.employee_id in group by

```
select epi.employee_id,group_concat(epi.project_name) 
from user u inner join employee_projects_info epi 
on epi.employee_id= u.id 
group by epi.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

make group by id and concat all project name:

```
 select epi.employee_id, group_concat(epi.project_name)
from user u    inner join employee_projects_info epi on epi.employee_id= u.id
group by epi.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to get all the users along with their projects. You can get that data by

```
select u.id,epi.id,epi.project_name
from users u
inner join employee_projects_info epi on epi.employee_id = u.id
```

To get the comma separated project names for every user, you'll have to use `group by` in the above query. You can find that query in other people's answers.